# Parsing AndroidManifest.xml with XmlResourceParser not working as expected

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I need to parse the `AndroidManifest.xml` to retrieve some additional information that are unavailable through `PackageManager`.

I have the following code:

```
try
{
    AssetManager assetManager = createPackageContext(getPackageName(), 0).getAssets();
    XmlResourceParser xml = assetManager.openXmlResourceParser("AndroidManifest.xml");
    int eventType = xml.getEventType();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {
        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "START_DOCUMENT");
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "START_TAG: " + xml.getName());
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "END_TAG: " + xml.getName());
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "TEXT: " + xml.getText());
        }
        eventType = xml.next();
    }

    xml.close();
}
catch ( XmlPullParserException
      | PackageManager.NameNotFoundException
      | IOException ignore) { }
```

I expected to get all tags from the XML file, but all I am getting is this:

```
START_DOCUMENT
START_DOCUMENT
START_TAG: manifest
END_TAG: manifest
```

...which is not what I expected.

---

I am not sure why `START_DOCUMENT` is there twice, but what bothers me most is that I don't get any tags inside of `<manifests>` tag.

Am I doing  something wrong with the parsing or are those tags not available at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `xml.next()` instead of `xml.getEventType()` because you are dealing with a **FILE** and `next()` method always starts at the value of **zero** as the file starting point and ends at the value of **one** if the file was empty.

I hope this will help.

```
// for the sake of dealing with a file
int eventType = xml.next();
```

**The full code:**

```
final String TAG = "cccc";

try
{
    AssetManager assetManager = createPackageContext(getPackageName(), 0).getAssets();
    XmlResourceParser xml = assetManager.openXmlResourceParser("AndroidManifest.xml");
    int eventType = xml.next();

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "START_DOCUMENT");
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "START_TAG: " + xml.getName());
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "END_TAG: " + xml.getName());
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "TEXT: " + xml.getText());
        }
        eventType = xml.next();
    }

    xml.close();
}
catch ( XmlPullParserException
      | PackageManager.NameNotFoundException
      | IOException ignore) { }
```

**The result when running on actual device**

```
 D/cccc: START_TAG:START_DOCUMENT
 D/cccc: START_TAG: manifest
 D/cccc: START_TAG: uses-sdk
 D/cccc: END_TAG: uses-sdk
 D/cccc: START_TAG: uses-permission
 D/cccc: END_TAG: uses-permission
 D/cccc: START_TAG: uses-permission
 D/cccc: END_TAG: uses-permission
.
.
.
 D/cccc: END_TAG: application
 D/cccc: END_TAG: manifest
```

I ran into same problem when I used emulator to run the code.

Referring to [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49300152/8963654) the code will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Mohammed's code will work, for non-Instant Run builds.

With Instant Run, the APK that is on the device only vaguely resembles the actual APK that would be deployed to production. Some of the core APK might be what is in your real APK, but the rest of your app gets pushed over as some form of add-on, which the Instant Run environment can blend together to create something that runs kinda like your app would. The benefit here is that those add-ons can be pushed over quickly, as they are smaller and do not require a full on-device install.

The downside is that an Instant Run app *isn't* your APK, and so things that peek inside the APK may work differently on an Instant Run build than they do on a regular build.

I am surprised that the manifest is something that the Instant Run environment can synthesize on the fly based on these add-ons. That being said, reading the manifest as a resource definitely qualifies as "unusual", and so on that front it is not shocking in retrospect that Instant Run breaks this code.

So, if you really need this read-the-manifest-XML feature, you'll need to disable Instant Run for your IDE. Alternatively, find some other solution that doesn't require reading the manifest XML (e.g., save your desired "which runtime permissions are optional?" information in Java `static` fields).